# ASP:NET MVC 5 - Localize data-val-number validation message

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I’m working on a ASP.NET MVC 5 Application. I’m using attributes to validate my models. In the back-end combined with EF 6 and in the front-end combined with jQuery validate (exactly like in the MVC samples and templates).
A lot of my models have some properties of type int (usually the have a range attribute to validate them). Inside my razor pages I use the standard HTML helper methods to create input elements for my models. If I create a textbox for an int property ASP adds some jQuery validation attributes to the element (every attribute is localized expect data-val-number).

Here is an example:

Model:

```
[Range( 1, 1000, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidationError_Range_propertyName_min_max" )]
[Required( ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidationError_Required_propertyName" )]
public Int32 Number { get; set; }
```

HTML:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Nummer must be a number." data-val-range="Nummer muss zwischen 1 und 1000 sein." 
data-val-range-max="1000" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-required="Nummer ist erforderlich." id="Number" name="Card.Number" placeholder="Nummer" type="text" 
value="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" class="input-validation-error" aria-describedby="Number-error">
```

How can I localize the data-val-number attribute?

Btw. Searching for this problem only returns answers specific to ASP.Net MVC 3 and 4. I hope there is a good solution implemented in MVC 5.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for it with MVC 5?

Comment: same issue in ASP.Net Core 2.1, I added `data-val-number` attribute manually to solve it.